# Do a sum() with group by thing like mysql query do but with multiple array in php

Tags: php, arrays

here is the thing what I'm doing now, I got an array from database like this :

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=13)
      'wop_product_owner_id' => string '100007' (length=6)
      'wop_product_id' => string '100002' (length=6)
      'wop_product_price' => string '18.80' (length=5)
      'wop_product_count' => string '2.00' (length=4)
      'wop_product_unit' => string 'kg' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=13)
      'wop_product_owner_id' => string '100007' (length=6)
      'wop_product_id' => string '100001' (length=6)
      'wop_product_price' => string '35.00' (length=5)
      'wop_product_count' => string '4.00' (length=4)
      'wop_product_unit' => string 'kg' (length=6)
```

All I need to do is merge each item with total 'wop_product_price*wop_product_count' as a new array in this array which it has the same 'wop_product_owner_id', The new array should be like this:

```js
array (size=1) 
    0 => 
        array (size=5) 
            'woner_id' => string '100007' (length=6) 
            'woner_name' => string 'Jack' (length=6) 
            'woner_photo' => string '' (length=5) 
            'woner_total' => float '177.6.00' 
            'woner_paid' => boolean 'false'
```

Basically, just like you do a query with sum() and group by in Mysql.
And, I already got a way to do this, here is the code:

$tmps = array();

```
    foreach ($products as $p) {
        $owner_id = $p['wop_product_owner_id'];

        if (empty($tmps)) {
            $tmps[] = array(
                'woner_id' => $p['wop_product_owner_id'],
                'woner_name' => $p['wop_product_owner_name'],
                'woner_photo' => $p['wop_product_owner_photo'],
                'woner_total' => (float) $p['wop_product_price'] * (float) $p['wop_product_count'],
                'woner_paid' => (int) $p['wop_product_payment_id'] > 0
            );
        } else {
            foreach ($tmps as $key => $value) {
                if (array_search($owner_id, $value) === FALSE) {
                    $tmps[] = array(
                        'woner_id' => $p['wop_product_owner_id'],
                        'woner_name' => $p['wop_product_owner_name'],
                        'woner_photo' => $p['wop_product_owner_photo'],
                        'woner_total' => (float) $p['wop_product_price'] * (float) $p['wop_product_count'],
                        'woner_paid' => (int) $p['wop_product_payment_id'] > 0
                    );
                } else {
                    $tmps[$key]['woner_total'] = (float) $tmps[$key]['woner_total'] + (float) $p['wop_product_price'] * (float) $p['wop_product_count'];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $tmps;
```

But, I don't like it actually, I thought there must be have some way more graceful than this! What you think? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
foreach ($products as $p) {
    $owner_id = $p['wop_product_owner_id'];

    if (empty($tmps[$owner_id])) {
        $tmps[$owner_id] = array(
            'woner_id' => $p['wop_product_owner_id'],
            'woner_name' => $p['wop_product_owner_name'],
            'woner_photo' => $p['wop_product_owner_photo'],
            'woner_total' => (float) $p['wop_product_price'] * (float) $p['wop_product_count'],
            'woner_paid' => (int) $p['wop_product_payment_id'] > 0
        );
    } else {

                $tmps[$owner_id]['woner_total'] = (float) $tmps[$key]['woner_total'] + (float) $p['wop_product_price'] * (float) $p['wop_product_count'];


    }
}

return $tmps;
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, Your way looks better than mine!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new way came from @budirec:

```
    $tmps = array();
    foreach ($products as $p) {
        $owner_id = 'owner_' . $p['wop_product_owner_id'];
        if (!isset($tmps[$owner_id])) {
            $tmps[$owner_id] = array(
                'woner_id' => $p['wop_product_owner_id'],
                'woner_name' => $p['wop_product_owner_name'],
                'woner_photo' => $p['wop_product_owner_photo'],
                'woner_total' => (float) $p['wop_product_price'] * (float) $p['wop_product_count'],
                'woner_paid' => (int) $p['wop_product_payment_id'] > 0
            );
        } else {
            $tmps[$owner_id]['woner_total'] = (float) $tmps[$owner_id]['woner_total'] + (float) $p['wop_product_price'] * (float) $p['wop_product_count'];
        }
    }

    return $tmps;
```